# Copy some extra file in data folder after build in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build, build-pipeline

I have to copy two text files and a folder to my **build data folder** after finishing the build (exe) for windows platform. Each time I build, I want to copy these files and folder from assets to build data folder. Is this possible in unity? Cause sometime I forget to copy desired file in data folder and my player does not work correctly.

Answer (score 8):

You can subscribe a static method to [PostprocessBuild.OnPostprocessBuild](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Build.IPostprocessBuild.OnPostprocessBuild.html)
This method will be called every time a build is finished.
So your code might look like this:

```
using UnityEditor;
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor.Build;
using UnityEngine;

class MyCustomBuildProcessor : IPostprocessBuild
{
    public int callbackOrder { get { return 0; } }
    public void OnPostprocessBuild(BuildTarget target, string path)
    {
        File.Copy("sourceFilePath","destinationFilePath");
    }
}
```

Comment: you have forget to add system.io

Comment: Good point, fixed that.
Well, you could also use an editor window to set the paths and store them for example in your EditorPrefs (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorPrefs.html).
To get the path to your project you can use Application.dataPath.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want your own custom editor build function. You can do this with a custom editor menu item.

[Unity Editor Extensions – Menu Items](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/unity-editor-extensions-menu-items)

Here is what the code might look like:

```
[MenuItem("MyBuildMenu/MyBuildMenuItem")]
static void BuildAndCopyItems()
{
    File.Copy("path1","path2"); // copy your files
    BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(); // build the player
}
```

you'll need to pass the correct arguments to BuildPlayer:

[BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer.html)

The file containing this script will need to be within your project in a folder called 'Editor'.

And you'll get a new menu item in the Unity editor to perform your custom build:

[image]

Comment: You don't need custom build to do this